# PHP money_format with currency symbol

Tags: php

How do you format a number with it's currency symbol the correct location? Is it better to just allows the end user determine what their currency symbol is by typing it in?

Comment: "with it's currency symbol in front" --- not every currency symbol is located in front of a price. I would even say - the more are placed behind the price.

Comment: given stuff like exchange rates, I'd imagine this is more complicated than just choosing the correct display format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can use with `LC_MONETARY`

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56

// Italian national format with 2 decimals`
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $number) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the $ or Euro Symbol (Not sure how to type it)